# python - How do I extract the id from an unsupervised text classification

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, pca, text-classification, unsupervised-learning

So I have the following dataframe:

```
id     text
342    text sample
341    another text sample
343    ...
```

And the following code:

```
X = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text']).todense()
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
data2D = pca.fit_transform(X)
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters), random_state=10)
cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(data2D)
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(data2D, cluster_labels)
print(silhouette_avg)
y_lower = 10
for i in range(n_clusters):
    # here I would like to get the id's of each item per cluster
    # so that I know which list of id's falls into which cluster
```

Now, how can I see which id falls in which cluster, is this something that can be done? Also is my approach correct in order to "clusterize" these text documents?

Please not that I might have skipped some code in order to keep the question short

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways to perform document classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification). K-Means is one way. To say what you are doing is the best would be impossible with looking at the data and use case and exploring other methods.

If you'd like to stick with KMeans, I suggest you go read the documentation on the scikit-learn website one more time. You'll notice in the example how you can get the predicted class label for each point by calling the `labels_` property on the fit classifier (note: not the result of `fit_transform` as you currently have).